# ZF2: Conditionally counting from another table

Tags: sql, zend-framework2

I have two tables, notifications and analytics.

Notifications has got the column: id

Analytics has got the columns: type, notification_id

In my NotificationTable Model, I need to query all notifications and return a count of how many times the notification_id = id when the type = "notification".

I guess I'd have to join with analytics, and use count expression but I am getting only one row for some reason, with an invalid count.

```
$select->from($this->table)
      ->columns(array('*' ,'sum_view' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('sum(CASE analytics.type = "notification" WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'),
        'view_count' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('count(analytics.notification_id)')))
      ->join('analytics' , 'notification.id = analytics.notification_id', array('type', 'notification_id'), 'right')
      //->group('notification.id')
      ->order('notification.id DESC');
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `where` to filter rows with type = "notification"
2. Remove `group` and `order`, extra `select` and `join` params
3. Use `COUNT DISTINCT` to prevent duplicates

---

```
$select->from($this->table)
       ->columns(array('*' ,'cnt' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(DISTINCT notification.id)'))
       ->join('analytics' , 'notification.id = analytics.notification_id')
       ->where(array('analytics.type' => 'notification'));
```

Comment: This way if there are no analytics for the notification, I will not get the row at all. I need to show it and have the column count = 0 if no analytics were found for that notification.

Comment: Try this query: `SELECT count(DISTINCT notifications.id) 
FROM notifications JOIN analytics ON analytics.notification_id = notifications.id
WHERE analytics.type = 'invalid-value'`. It will return 0 as result, right?